# grab last-child but not of a certain class

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying this: `inner.children('.image:not(dont):last-child').width();`

What is the correct way to combine not(classname) and :last-child?

Comment: all you needed is a `.dont` in there. But why do you retrieve `.width` of something that might not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
inner.children('.image:last-child:not(.dont)').width()
```

Comment: Without the `"` around the class selector.